# Concurrent Modification of HashMap Members

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap

I have a map defined

```
private static HashMap<Object, Object> myMap;
```

It is populated in a single thread and then that single thread spawns more threads that alter the data inside the map elements, but do not alter the map structure (no removes/puts/etc). Also, each thread alters one and only one unique member of the map (no two threads alter the same member).

My question is: will the main thread see the changes to the hashmap members, once all changes are complete? If not, would adding volatile to the declaration work, or would it only guarantee other threads see changes to the structure? Thanks

EDIT: Code that hopefully highlights what I'm doing in a more clear way

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestingRandomStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HashMap<Object, Object> myMap = new HashMap();
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        //myMap is populated by this thread, and the objects inside are initialized, but are left largely empty
        populate();

        for (Object o : myMap.values()) {
            Runnable r = new Task(o);
            pool.execute(r);
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        try {
            pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {;}

        //How do I gurantee that the objects inside myMap are displayed correctly with all the data that was just loaded by seperate threads,
        //or is it already guranteed?
        displayObjectData();
    }

    public static class Task implements Runnable {
        private Object o;

        public Task(Object o) {this.o = o;}

        public void run() {
            try {
                o.load(); //o contains many complicated instance variables that will be created and written to
            } catch (Exception e) {;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this just a bad example? Because `String` is immutable. Can you give a more realistic example?

Comment: No, there's no guarantee other threads will see changes.  Making the map volatile won't help because you're not modifying the field.

Comment: What do you mean by "alter the data inside the map elements"?  `String`s are immutable, but you aren't removing/putting?

Comment: It is. In reality I'm using a much more complicated object, I'll edit it just to be Object, Object

Comment: There are no guarantees that threads will see changes to the nested objects. Making the map `volatile` won't help as @shmosel points out. Adding a `synchronized` block would be the simplet way to make this work - other solutions require a much deeper understanding of the structure of what you are changing and how you are changing it.

Comment: Would using a ConcurrentHashMap guarantee changes to members are visible to other threads?

Comment: @sufah1 the fact a object is referenced in a ConcurrentHashMap doesn't make the object any more thread safe.

Comment: I think CHM might work if you use atomic operations like `compute()`.

Comment: @shmosel I don't think this is true. I don't know what locking constructs a CHM uses in all operations, but you'd be relying on some pretty intricate implementation details if you relied on a CHM providing visibility to _changes_ of referenced objects; unless you removed and reinserted...

Comment: @BoristheSpider CHM has visibility guarantees for its atomic operations. The question is whether it's safe to rely on that without actually replacing the value.

Comment: It provides visibility guarantees on the reference in the map, rather than its contents - so you might be able to rely on it as an implementation detail but it's dubious. As [Peter Lawrey said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407458/concurrent-modification-of-hashmap-members?noredirect=1#comment89786718_51407458) "_the fact a object is referenced in a ConcurrentHashMap doesn't make the object any more thread safe_"

Comment: @BoristheSpider Not quite. There is a *happens-before* guarantee between writes and reads, which other changes can piggyback on, if done correctly.

Comment: @shmosel yes, but that doesn't help you. You're mutating a non-threadsafe object to which the reference is published. Once the `computeXX` method returns there is a happens-before relationship guaranteed. But you are fiddling with an object whose reference has been published during that method - where no such guarantees hold.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's implied that the computation happens under a lock, but you're right that it's not clearly specified. Would you concede if the list were thread-safe?

Comment: If the structure being mutated is also threadsafe then we're all good. There is obviously a risk of partial changes being published, depending on the structure being mutated - for example if multiple things were added to the List - but we're in good old fashioned race hazard territory, rather than UB. If changes were done under a lock then threadsafety isn't really a concern as a lock would provide a full membar...

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: in your example, the map doesn't get accessed in other threads, only objects which are referenced by the map.

The objects themselves should be thread safe due to the way they are being used.

Note: if you used a parallelStream() the code would be simpler.

---

> will other threads see the changes to the hashmap members?

Probably, but there is no guarentee

> If not, would adding volatile to the declaration work,

`volatile` on the field only adds a read barrier on the reference to the Map. (Unless you change the field to point to another Map when you will get a write barrier.)

> or would it only guarantee other threads see changes to the structure?

No, only guaranteed see changes to the `myMap` reference not changes to the Map or anything in the Map. i.e. the guarantee is very shallow.

There is a number of ways you can provide thread safety however the simplest is to `synchronized` the object in the on write and read.  There are tricks you can do with `volatile` fields however it is high dependant on what you are doing as to whether thi will work.

Comment: The OP has added a code example after you posted your answer and after reviewing the question’s code example, [I consider it completely safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51658787/2711488), due to the way it uses an `ExecutorService`. The confusion stems from the OP’s term “hashmap members”, which is a red herring, as the hash map is populated before the concurrent operation and doesn’t change afterwards, in other words, is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for picking up on that change. It's a common misconception that if an object is referenced in a map it some how has a special relationship with that map.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ConcurrentHashMap`.

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset.

This means changes done by a thread are visible to another thread reading value for the same key. But the two can interfere.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey said in the comments of my post that "the fact a object is referenced in a ConcurrentHashMap doesn't make the object any more thread safe", so I am a tad confused

Comment: @sufah1, I think the case is that if you have `ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>` you cannot just do `map.get("key").add("another_value")`. You might need to do `List l = map.get("key"); l.add("another_value"); map.put("key", l);`. Also if two threads execute that code then you might get missing updates. In your particular case `ConsurrentHashMap` will work

Comment: If your `List` is not threadsafe then the behaviour of the example is undefined - the CHM is irrelevant.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, yes, this is what I've said in the comment. But it is valid only if several threads perform said update operation. If one performs update using `replace/put` and another thread only reads using get then it will work.

Comment: Nope. It is **undefined**. Concurrent access or modification of a non-threadsafe collection is UB. It may throw an exception, it may do nothing, it may cause the world to end. Lost updates would be the least of your issues. "_If one performs update using replace/put and another thread only reads using get then it will work_" is incorrect.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, if value in for a key CHM is replaced (not `map.get(key).add(element)` but `l = map.get(key); l.add(element); map.replace(key, l)`) I think CHM guarantees that subsequent read for the same key will get fresh data. If one thread only populates CHM and another one iterates over the keys and executes get the second thread either get fresh value or get nothing, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it will guarantee that the other threads will see the new _reference_ but it makes absoltely no guarantees about the contents of that object. For example I might see the updated `size` field but not an updated `elementData[]` field - because it was resized and replaced; access would then throw an exception because whilst the `ArrayList` thinks its size is `x` it only has data up to `y < x`. The point is really that there is no way that the CHM can guarantee visibility of the innards of the objects it references - how could it?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176283/discussion-between-ivan-and-boris-the-spider).

Comment: Forget about the map. It's not safe to have 2 threads updating the same list at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there are no objects embedded in other objects, all data structures consisting of multiple objects are reference graphs, or in other words, a collection of objects is a collection of references and a map with key and value objects is a map containing references to these objects.

Therefore, your objects never became “hashmap members”, but are just *referenced* by your hashmap. So, to discuss the thread safety of your code, the existence of the `HashMap` is just a red herring, as your multi-threaded code never sees any artifact of the `HashMap`.

You have code creating several distinct object, then submitting `Task` instances, each containing a reference to one of these objects, to an `ExecutorService` to be processed. Assuming that these object do not share mutable state, this is a straight-forward thread safe approach.

After waiting for the completion of all jobs, the main thread can be sure to see the result of all actions made within the jobs, i.e. the modifications made to these objects. It will again be entirely irrelevant whether you use that `HashMap` or anything else to get a reference to one of these objects to look at these modifications.

It would be different if you were modifying keys of a map in a way that it affects their equality or hash code, but that’s independent from thread safety concerns. You must never modify map keys in such a way, even in single threaded code, and violating this contract would even break thread safe maps. But since your objects are referenced as values, there is no such problem.

There is only one corner case to pay attention to. Your waiting for completion contains the line `catch (InterruptedException e) {;}`, so there is no full guaranty that after the execution of the statement truly all jobs have been completed, but this is the requirement for the visibility guaranty. Since you seem to assume that interruption should never happen, you should use something like `catch(InterruptedException e) { throw new AssertionError(e); }`, to be sure that violations of that assumption do not happen silently, while at the same time, get the full visibility guaranty, as now the `displayObjectData();` statement can only be reached when all jobs have been completed (or `Long.MAX_VALUE` seconds elapsed which no-one of us will ever witness).